# GCP Service account cannot read skus

Tags: google-cloud-platform

For a couple of days I expirience a strange thing: my service acount does not have permission to read skus from GCP api.
This call:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer <service account acccess token>" https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services/6F81-5844-456A/skus?fields=skus,nextPageToken
```

returns

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

If I change the access token to be a token from a normal (`@gmail.com`) account - it works, but with a service account I get 403. My service accounts have all the permissions, I even gave Owner role to one of them for thest - didn't work.

Any ideas? Did Google changed something regarding the access from service accounts to this apis?

Comment: Did you add the service account email address to the billing account IAM? Billing accounts are separate from Google Cloud projects.

Comment: This started for me last week, and I'm at a loss as well. 
@JohnHanley can you elaborate on "Billing Account IAM"?  https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/BILLING_ID doesn't have IAM options from what I can gather.

Comment: @kgreen We've created a ticket to Google, they have a bug, it seems. I've made a test  calling the api multiple times, with SA access token, and sometimes I receive success, sometimes 403 error (same request, same access token). It's completly random. No response to the ticket so far. Yes, it started last week.

Comment: Yeah I'm getting the same. Sometimes results, sometimes errors. Can you link the ticket so I can follow?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access

Comment: @kgreen It's support ticket - not public. But nothing interesting so far. Will update you on the progress.

Comment: @kgreen The support wrote to us to check again. Maybe they've fixed  something.

Comment: I can confirm it's working again.